# Invalid syntax in this simple Python application

Tags: python, syntax

Getting an invalid syntax when creating the template_value variable:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        blogPosts_query = BlogPost.all().order('-postDate')
        blogPosts = blogPosts_query.fetch(10)

        if  users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            url = url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

        template_value = (
            'blogPosts': blogPosts,
            'url': url,
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
        )

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

The error fires specifically on the `'blogPosts': blogPosts` line.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to create a dictionary with round brackets rather than curly ones - change it to:

```
    template_value = {
        'blogPosts': blogPosts,
        'url': url,
        'url_linktext': url_linktext,
    }
```

... and the syntax is valid again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use () for template value? Dictionaries use curly braces.